# How to constructor in header, definition in source

Tags: c, oop, struct, header-files

I've a struct like this (I've coded the C `struct` like a C++ `class` to demonstrate what I am thinking; but I am working in C.):

```
//This is a source file
typedef struct _MyType
{
     void test() { printf("works!"); }
}MyType;
```

But I want to define my struct like that: (That not works)

```
//This is a header file
typedef struct _MyType
{
     void test();
}MyType;

//This is a source file
MyType::test() { printf("works!"); }
```

I've tried some more things but I can't do it again. (I want to use `structs` like `classes`)

How can I achieve this OOP-like separation in C?

Comment: `_MyType` is a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Seems to be c++ not c, adjust tags (?)

Comment: @dastrobu, The OP is trying to get C++-like behaviour in C.

Comment: @dastrobu Yes, I'm trying to make a class like struct in C.

Comment: As far as I know, c does not allow method definitions in a struct and has no scope operator (`::`) so its c++.

Comment: For an absolute abomination of how to do C++ method tables in C, look no further than the C-based COM-macros for Windows COM (which amazingly midl *still* emits).  What you're asking to do is many thing, but trivial is *not* among them.

Comment: look up function pointers in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define functions inside `struct` in C programming.

However you can have function pointers inside `struct`

Something like this :-

```
typedef struct{
     void (*test)();
}MyType;


void test(MyType* self) { printf("works!"); }
int main()
{

    MyType *m =malloc(sizeof(MyType));
    m->test=test;
    m->test(m);

    free(m);
}
```

Comment: This is about as close as it gets to C++ if you stick to C. :)

Comment: Well the instance struct could only have one pointer to a class struct which carries all function pointers to the methods. Then define some macros to handle the data and what you get is a simplified version of the Python-C-API...

Comment: I'll use (my) this implemention for a interface. Namely source will be in my program, header will be outside; a c++/c shared library will get my functions via this struct from my c application. I want to protect my c functions, also my functions will effect my c application. Any suggesstion about this?

Comment: @MonoLightStudios Yes, use C++ :D

Comment: @MonoLightStudios: Or pass your data as struct (or array) and the callback function as function pointer, like you do for [qsort](http://linux-documentation.com/en/man/man3/qsort.html).